Failed to lookup symbol 'TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate': dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate): symbol not found
I reported an error while exporting tflite_flutter as framework through the flutter module to the iOS native project.
environment:
flutter 3.7.0，xcode 14
dependencies:
tflite_flutter 0.10.4
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol
'TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate': dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate): symbol not found
#0 DynamicLibrary.lookup (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:33)
#1 TensorFlowLiteBindings._TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreatePtr (package:tflite_flutter/src/bindings/tensorflow_lite_bindings_generated.dart:336)
#2 TensorFlowLiteBindings._TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate (package:tflite_flutter/src/bindings/tensorflow_lite_bindings_generated.dart)
#3 TensorFlowLiteBindings.TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate (package:tflite_flutter/src/bindings/tensorflow_lite_bindings_generated.dart)
#4 new InterpreterOptions (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter_options.dart:36)
#5 Detector._loadModel (package:tf_module/service/detector_service.dart:109)
#6 Detector.start (package:tf_module/service/detector_service.dart:99)
<asynchronous suspension>

I saw that someone said that there was a way to solve it, but it didn't work for me.

In Xcode, go to Target Runner > Build Settings > Strip Style
Change from All Symbols to Non-Global Symbols

Does anyone know how to fix this, please.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't post image of error messages and Please refer Why is uploading images of code/errors on Stack Overflow such a big no?
